# Is there an Image Done Rasterizing event?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Working on a scene entrance transition/animation, i'm facing stutter if the scene contains images.

So the first thing that comes to mind is, wait for those images to get loaded AND rasterized before starting the animation. Thus far, i've tried this [images-loaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) plugin.

```
      Polymer.dom(this).appendChild(child);
      imagesLoaded(child, { background: true },() => {
        setClasses(child, ENTERING);
      });
```

It didn't change the behavior of my entrance transition:

- the transition starts without the images being rendered
- while the transition is running, the images get loaded and rasterized and start rendering on screen, causing stutter on the entrance transition.

Is there a way to know when an image is actually done rasterizing?

Comment: can you post some of your code? i would imagine that if you waited to apply the transition until after the image had finished loading with the images-loaded plugin, that it should work. But cant confirm without code

Comment: @haxxxton updated the question

Comment: Will probably need the html and css too. The guidelines for posting a question ask for you to supply [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help.